# How to train independent keras models in different nodes (embarrassingly parallel workload)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dask

I have a python script with some data (of size that fits in memory) and I want to learn (in X different nodes on-prem) X different versions of these keras models (could be tensorflow as well) on relatively different versions of this data and then combine the results (it sort of resembles an ensemble of models). I don't need to further distribute the training of the keras models, as it is good enough that they run on multi-threading mode. I thought this would be a relatively common setup, but I have not found any working examples online.

Does anyone know the best approach to this?

1. Is Dask the right tool for this? It does not look promising: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2333 
   Is it the same issue with tensorflow? According to this it should be ok to do such kind of trivial parallelization with tensorflow:
   http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/02/11/dask-tensorflow
   So I incline to think that the right path is to use map dask operations instead of delay.
2. Do I need to create a TensorFlow cluster when I don't want to further parallelize the training of the tensorflow model? https://ml.dask.org/tensorflow.html
3. Is there any workaround to it using Scikit-learn wrapper and maybe joblib?

Any clues on the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with creating `X` identical networks and training them one after the other ?

Comment: Well, I would like to train them in parallel on different nodes to speed up the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to run embarassingly parallel workloads with Dask.  Here is the standard example that runs through then: https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html

As you note by pointing to [this issue](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2333), TensorFlow (and by extension Keras), doesn't play nicely with other systems.  If the workload that you're running creates, trains, evaluates and then forgets the tensorflow objects then you should be fine.  The problem arises when you try to pass Tensorflow graphs between different machines.  There are bugs in TensorFlow which stop that from working well.

Comment: Right, thanks for that, so you mean that the main issue is to move around the keras/tensorflow model regardless the parallelization strategy with Dask? Then either I need to 1) let Dask move data around doing something like: `client.map(train_and_evaluate, hyper_param_list, data=data)` or 2) write/read from disk inside the functions to parallelize. 
Given that  my data is about 200MB and I have nfs access to shared data cluster, what would you reckon is the best strategy?